How to add google adsense ads txt file in Angular project.?
The issue you're facing with Google AdSense likely stems from how Angular serves static files and how servers handle these files. Let's break down the steps to ensure your ads.txt file is correctly set    up in your Angular project:
i want to add my ads txt file on angulr project and check www.exampe.com/ads.txt data proper show but google adsense give same error
any one give me the structer where i place txt file in project etc

how you run angular app on prod? nginx/apache? or with serve? If some servers - look they config and add ads.txt in angular.json assets (like favicon.ico)
